# ToString adding "" everytime I using tostring in neo4j

Tags: neo4j

I do not know the type of value stored in my property of a node.
So I convert it into string using tostring
The problem is when I use tostring on an already string it adds "" to the string

i.e if my value is "nipun" 
then tostring("nipun") will give me ""nipun""
and if my value is 10
then tostring(10) will give me "10"

Is there a function which will not append these unnessary "" if the value is already string?

Answer (score 0):

At least in 2.1.4 the behaviour is different from what you describe: e.g.

```
return toString(toString(toString(10)))
```

returns `"10"`. To prove this, use e.g. [httpie](https://github.com/jakubroztocil/httpie) and run:

```
http -b -j localhost:7474/db/data/transaction/commit statements:='[{"statement": "return toString(toString(toString(10)))"}]'
```

which return the following JSON fragment:

```
{
    "errors": [], 
    "results": [
        {
            "columns": [
                "toString(toString(toString(10)))"
            ], 
            "data": [
                {
                    "row": [
                        "10"
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Thanks this behaviour is seen in 2.1.2. Let me check for a higer version